# Doing parallel processing in bash?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I've thousands of png files which I like to make smaller with `pngcrush`. I've a simple `find .. -exec` job, but it's sequential. My machine has quite some resources and I'd make this in parallel.

The operation to be performed on every png is:

```
pngcrush input output && mv output input
```

Ideally I can specify the maximum number of parallel operations.

Is there a way to do this with bash and/or other shell helpers? I'm Ubuntu or Debian.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to run multiple processes in parallel:

```
find /path -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P <nr_procs> sh -c 'pngcrush $1 temp.$$ && mv temp.$$ $1' sh
```

`xargs` will read the list of files produced by find (separated by 0 characters (`-0`)) and run the provided command (`sh -c '...' sh`) with one parameter at a time (`-n 1`).  xargs will run `<nr_procs>` (`-P <nr_procs>`) in parallel.

Comment: `$1` does not get populated, I also tried it with a minimal example without luck. xargs is 4.4.0, any idea?

Comment: I forgot to specify the value for $0.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: @BartSas What does the last 'sh' mean in `sh -c '...' sh`? Thanks!

Comment: @Todd It is the value of $0.  You can pass any value you want.

Answer (score 11):

You can use custom `find/xargs` solutions (see Bart Sas' answer), but when things become more complex you have -at least- two powerful options:

1. `parallel` (from package [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/))
2. [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: Deb and RPM packages: https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange

Comment: I highly recomment GNU parallel over the moreutils version. It is much more flexible.

Comment: find /path -print0 | parallel -0 pngcrush {} {.}.temp '&&' mv {.}.temp {}

Comment: @OleTange that's a great snippet and worth of its own answer so it gets the visibility it deserves!

Comment: @DrewNoakes Apparently it was not worth its own answer: -1 vote. Oh well.

Comment: @OleTange, well I disagree -- hence my +1. Seems that tokland also put your comment into their answer.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to give it some visibility. Obviously that -1 was not mine :)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ it can be done like:

```
find /path -print0 | parallel -0 pngcrush {} {.}.temp '&&' mv {.}.temp {}
```

Learn more:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  will love you for it.