# How to convert a find command to instead use grep to filter and then `exec` commands on output?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have a scenario where I need to execute a series of commands on each file that's found. This normally would work great, except I have over 100 files and folders to exclude from `find`'s results for execution. This becomes unwieldy and non-executable from the shell directly.  It seems like it would be optimal to use an "exclusion file" similar to how `tar` or `grep` allows for such files.

Since `find` does not accept a file for exclusion, but `grep` does, I want to know: how can the following be converted to a command that would replace the exclusion (`prune`) and `exec` functions in `find` to instead utilize **`grep`** with an exclusion file (`grep -v -f excludefile`) to exclude the folders and files and then execute a series of commands on the result like the current command does it:

```
find $IN_PATH -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex "/(excluded1|excluded2|excluded3|...|excludedN)" -prune \
  -o -type f \
  -exec sh -c "( cmd -with_args 1 '{}'; cmd -args2 '{}'; cmd3 '{}') \
    | cmd4 | cmd5 | cmd6; cmd7 '{}'" \; \
  > output
```

As a side note (not critical), I've read that if you don't use `exec` this process becomes much less efficient and this process is already consuming over 100 minutes to execute each time that it's run, so I don't want to slow it down any more than is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

the best way i think of to fulfill your scenario , is split the one-liner  to two line and introduce xargs with parallel  .

```
find $IN_PATH -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex "/(excluded1|excluded2|excluded3|...|excludedN)" -prune \
  -o -type f  > /tmp/full_file_list
cat /tmp/full_file_list|grep -f excludefile |xargs -0 -n 1 -P <nr_procs> sh -c 'command here' >output
```

see [Bash script processing limited number of commands in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543139/bash-script-processing-limited-number-of-commands-in-parallel) and [Doing parallel processing in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811943/doing-parallel-processing-in-bash) to learn more about  parallel in bash

finding and command on files are facing disk-io conflicts in one liner , spilt the one-liner could speed up the process a little bit  ,

hint: remember to put your full_file_list/excludefile/output in your exclude rules , and always debug your command on a smaller directory to reduce waiting time

Comment: Right, thanks for that reminder. I was so stuck on keeping it all together that I didn't think of parallelizing the operation, which makes sense given that computation and disk reading parallelization should speed things up at least slightly. I'm curious: I'm hitting a hard-to-debug issue on one of the commands that, in this case, will be going through xargs now. (A rare `unexpected end of file`) Wonder if there's a way to capture an error and print out which file the error comes from? Perhaps I need to expand this out into some additional lines...

Comment: I'm having a strange issue with `xargs`. `printf "%s" "$list" > output` gives a clean list of output, but when I pass it through `xargs` I see spaces in file paths broken into newlines (ie, `printf "%s" "$list" | xargs -n 1 -P 1 sh -c 'echo "$0"'`). Am I missing some side effect of `xargs`? The "$list" variable seems to output fine and `-0` on xargs doesn't work at all since apparently newlines are used from the grep output.

Comment: better to update your question with  simplified but workable  piece of  code, with the unexpected output

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've [simplified the code into a chunk that hopefully illustrates it sufficiently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750498/why-would-xargs-split-input-on-spaces-and-how-to-resolve-it).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
find . -type f |
grep -v -f excludefile |
xargs whatever
```

With respect to `this process is already consuming over 100 minutes to execute` - that's almost certainly a problem with whatever command line you wrote to replace `whatever` above and we could probably help you improve that if you post a separate question.

Comment: AFAIK, the asker  is trying to build a md5sum snapshot of the file system,  which is definitely a time costing process

Comment: I don't see any indication of what they're trying to do so you may be right, idk, I'm just assuming there's a better way than `sh -c "( cmd -with_args 1 '{}'; cmd -args2 '{}'; cmd3 '{}') \
    | cmd4 | cmd5 | cmd6; cmd7 '{}'"` no matter what all those `cmd`s are.