# Why would xargs split input on spaces and how to resolve it?

Tags: bash, grep, find, echo, xargs

In the following `bash` script, I'm capturing file a file list from a path into a variable and then passing it on into `xargs` for further operations.

I've found that simply `echo`ing the variable gives each line with spaces appropriately with a newline terminator for each line.  However when I `printf` or `echo` this over to `xargs`, I'm finding that `xargs` appears to be splitting the input of each line by spaces as well.  I'll illustrate with the following example with comments including the result I'm seeing:

```
# Using GNU find:
list="$( find '$SOME_PATH' -type f )"

excluded_list="$( egrep -v -f FILE_WITH_PATTERNS_OF_FOLDERS_TO_EXCLUDE <<< $list )"

# This prints out just fine with lines such as "/some/path/here with spaces" on their own line, eg:
#   /some/path/here with spaces
#   /another/path/here with spaces
#   /and yet another/path/here with spaces
echo "$excluded_list"

# But this prints out a line such as the above example "/some/path/here with spaces" broken up like this instead:
#   /some/path/here 
#   with 
#   spaces
#   /another/path/here 
#   with 
#   spaces
#   /and 
#   yet
#   another/path/here 
#   with 
#   spaces
printf "%s" "$excluded_list" | xargs -n 1 -P 1 sh -c 'echo "$0"'
# And the same result as `printf` above:
echo "$excluded_list" | xargs -n 1 -P 1 sh -c 'echo "$0"'
```

Comment: If you want `xargs` to take whole lines rather than splitting on `[:blank:]` character class, you use `xargs -L 1`. I invite you to read the man-page for xargs for the explanation of the `-l[max-lines], --max-lines[=max-lines]` option.

Comment: "*`xargs` reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines*"

Answer (score 2):

It is an antipattern to assign multiple filenames into a single variable
because any special character except for a null byte may appear in the filename
and you cannot split the variable into original filenames again.

In your example `echo "$excluded_list"` *may* look like preserving the
original filenames but unfortunately it isn't.  Try to insert two or
more successive whitespaces in your pathname and see what happens.
As a first aid, you can wrap `$list` with double quotes as `<<< "$list"` but it
is no more than a provisional remedy.

The workarounds are:

1. To store the filenames in an array
2. To use a null byte as a delimiter and process the result via pipe

For instance you can say something like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    excluded_list+=("$f")
done < <(find "$SOME_PATH" -type f -print0 | egrep -v -z -Z -f FILE_WITH_PATTERNS_OF_FOLDERS_TO_EXCLUDE -)
for f in "${excluded_list[@]}"; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

or

```
find "$SOME_PATH" -type f -print0 | egrep -v -z -Z -f FILE_WITH_PATTERNS_OF_FOLDERS_TO_EXCLUDE - | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 1 sh -c 'echo "$0"'
```

Note that `-z` and `-Z` options are GNU grep's extensions and may not work on other platform.